# i686 CPU detected when trying to install an from an X86-64 Live CD

Tags: installation, 64-bit

Ok so when I put the live CDs in my pc it boots then displays ' this kernel required an X86-64 CPU, but only detected a i686 CPU. Unable to boot- please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU. '  is it because I'm ripping the ISO downloaded from a win 7 on to a cd then sticking it in a win XP?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have anything to do with what computer you are downloading and burning, and what computer you are installing on (or Windows for that matter). The issue is that the computer you are trying to install it on is a 32-bit computer, and you downloaded the 64-bit ISO. You need to download the 32-bit ISO and burn it.

Comment: Thanks but no CDs will work!!! HELP!!

Comment: Please delete all the ISOs on your computer and throw away the CD's you've already burned. Then please download http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso and burn it to a new CD. Then install it from that CD

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to that:

> Q: Does VB support 64 bit guests?
>
> A: Support for 64 bit guests was introduced at version 2.0.0. If you wish to create 64 bit guests then we recommend that you upgrade to the latest version. Note that VirtualBox also supports 64-bit guest operating systems, under the following conditions: You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see User Manual chapter 1.2, Software vs. hardware virtualization (VT-x and AMD-V), page 10) and a 64-bit host operating system.

*(source: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=8669#p33940)*